# Can't get files from /mnt/media_rw/

Tags: java, android

I have a problem: I can't read the files which I get from a USB storage connected to my device. When I open a Linux console I see that the files are located at `/mnt/media_rw/[HEX_ID]`. I've tried this :

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"key.txt");
```

But I can't read this file.

Comment: Could you provide the error message? Or some details about what is the result?

Comment: @DezsoGabos when I debug a file is not existst when I download a ES File Explorer and when I clicked in usb I was asked about permission usb connection and later I see a files

Comment: @DezsoGabos which code ?

Comment: @DezsoGabos what is a saveButton

Comment: One moment, I will get back to you.

Comment: Check if the Environment.getExternalStorageState(); is Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY
and check if the Environment.getExternalStorageState() is Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

`Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY && Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED`

If that is ok, then use the following method:

```
  File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()),"key.txt");
```

Comment: How I can check this and what Is hould to do when a storage is not : Environment.getExternalStorageState();

Comment: Just try the getExternalFilesDir method, and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Now I do not have this device I will check tommorow could you help me tommrow ?

Comment: If I am not too busy, sure.

Comment: But I think I have to use this :  <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"/>
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Whan I connect to thhis davice I can get this info about it  :

Comment: device = deviceIterator.next();
        manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
        i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
                + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
                + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
                + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n";

Comment: Dezso Gabos I get a false

Comment: Set the user permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Dezso Gabos i get this permissions

Comment: Did you try this:  File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(),"key.txt");

Comment: A file is not exist